# How to loop through a dataframe and count the number of occurrences of different strings and add their counts to other columns

Tags: r, loops, apply, dice

I am trying to create a set of functions that can create tables containing all combinations of different 8-sided gaming dice. My function creates a dataframe with all these combinations with the columns containing characters.

Now I want to do something like this:

Go through each row and every time I find a certain character, add 1 to the relevant new column.

I have tried writing a function to do this and using the apply functions, but I am new to R and have not been able to make this work.

This is the code I use to create the dataframe.

```
createDiceTable <- function(redDice=0,blackDice=0,blueDice=0){
red <- as.data.frame(c("Blank","Blank","Crit","Crit","Hit","Hit","Accuracy","HitHit"))
black <- as.data.frame(c("Blank","Blank","Hit","Hit","Hit","Hit","HitCrit","HitCrit"))
blue <- as.data.frame(c("Hit","Hit","Hit","Hit","Crit","Crit","Accuracy","Accuracy"))

result <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(c(replicate(redDice,red),replicate(blackDice,black),replicate(blueDice,blue))))

convertDice(result)
}
convert

convertDice <- function(df){
  df[,"Damage"] <- NA
  df[,"Accuracies"] <- NA
  df[,"Crits"] <- NA
  return(df)
}
```

I have tried this code for a function to apply to the dataframe that should count the number of dice having rolled "Hit" to the "Damage"-column

```
damageFunc <- function(x){if(x=="Hit") append(df["Damage"],1)}
```

I have tried applying it like this:

```
sapply(testdice,damageFunc)
```

Comment: Could you give us the end result dataframe or object you're looking for? Am I looking at a dataframe of dice rolls, then you want to compute statistics (e.g., total damage) with them?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(testdice)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(testdice, 20))`.

Comment: Also, you don't need `as.data.frame` with `expand.grid`.